# Laravel 5.2 middleware auth not working as I expect

Tags: laravel

I've created the basic application used make:auth

I then renamed *HomeController* to *MembersController*

When assessing the controller it redirect to the home page but it only does this when

```
//$this->middleware('auth');
```

isn't commented. It works fine when uncommented, with the exception theres no authorization.

Any ideas on why its behaving this way

Comment: To clarify, with `$this->middleware('auth');` uncommented, you want it to redirect to what...`site_url/login`? You should provide us with which route you are trying to access and which method inside the controller you're calling (ie: `index`, `someCustomMethod`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php then change the redirect URL,where you want to redirect after login